# INSERT row INTO tbody

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть таблица :

```
<table id="tbl_2">
<thead>
      <tr>
         <th>A</th>
         <th>A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>B</th>
         <th>B</th>
      </tr>    
</thead>
<tbody> </tbody>
<tfoot>
      <tr><td colspan="2">p</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2">p</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Вот так, две строки вставляются криво — в `tfoot`, а хочу в `tbody`:

```
function fn1() {

  for(var r=2; r<4; r++) {
    document.getElementById('tbl_2').insertRow(r).insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'a';
    document.getElementById('tbl_2').rows[r].insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'b';
  }
}
```

Так — не проходит вообще :

```
for(var r=2; r<4; r++) {
 document.getElementById('tbl_2').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].insertRow(r).insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'a';
 document.getElementById('tbl_2').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].rows[r].insertCell(1).innerHTML = 'b';
}
```

Пробовал `.tBodies[0]`. вместо `.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0]`.
Где-то видел через `id` под `tbody`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно делать?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#tbl_2 tbody')`

Comment: спасибо, но так не работает : document.querySelector('#tbl_2 tbody').insertRow(r).insertCell(0).innerHTML = 'a';

Comment: @Deonis, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать через querySelector?

Comment: @Alex: Ваш первоночальный код, использующий DOM API, можно легко исправить: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/L801w2uw/

Comment: @Oleg, посмотрите куда попадают а и b : alert('html tbl2 : '+document.getElementById('tbl_2').innerHTML);

Comment: Мой косяк, во втором варианте, который 'не проходил', был в отсчете цикла. Когда вносим в tbody, то считать нужно с нуля, без учета шапки : for(var r=0; r<4; r++) . Вот так уже работает.

Comment: Вот что смутило уважаемого Deonis по поводу insertRow/insertCell, и как делать правильно, хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: кстати, если пустое, то наиболее эффективно построить строку со всеми ктроками tbody и использовать .innerHTML для замены tbody. см. https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.12.0/js/grid.base.js#L3545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать

Я не знаю, что для вас считается правильным, т.к. даже в двух строчках вашего кода, для меня кроется загадка. Смотрите такой пример, может и пригодится:

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('#tbl_2 tbody'),
  row, cell;
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  row = tbody.insertRow(i);
  for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(k);
    cell.textContent = 'TD ' + i + '-' + k;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl_2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">p</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

И почему вы решили делать с помощью insertRow/insertCell - для меня тоже тайна, покрытая мраком.

Comment: Ваш код работает так, как мне нужно. Спасибо.